# uploading data with file guzzle laravel

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

i'm trying to send data with image for profile and i'm getting this error:

Invalid resource type: array

data:

```
Array ( [name] => staff [userId] => 1 [phoneNumber] => 88888888888888888 [postalCode] => 123123 [city] => asdas [state] => asdasd [country] => asdasd [skills] => Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 10 ) [image] => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile Object ( [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => Screenshot from 2020-04-16 13-37-59.png [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image/png [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0 [hashName:protected] => [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /tmp/phpt76Li7 [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpt76Li7 ) [dob] => 2010-04-14 [staff_id] => 2 [gender] => male [first_name] => norma [last_name] => fatohi [token] => eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6Ijc1MWJmZTZkMDM0YTk3MTI1OGQwNGQwYTM4NjYxNTUwY2Q5OWRkMDUzY2NjMTE0NTUzODNhMjViZGNmNTBiMTUwZmQyN2IxYzEwMDhlOWFlIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiNzUxYmZlNmQwMzRhOTcxMjU4ZDA0ZDBhMzg2NjE1NTBjZDk5ZGQwNTNjY2MxMTQ1NTM4M2EyNWJkY2Y1MGIxNTBmZDI3YjFjMTAwOGU5YWUiLCJpYXQiOjE1ODgwNTAyMTAsIm5iZiI6MTU4ODA1MDIxMCwiZXhwIjoxNjE5NTg2MjEwLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.VR6HwGg_4hTywTMofzdPfkobLgoDxOmzk1p2S7rhSFNrTfU1zhitX3jm4Ny6B5GeS-lxZI6o4vzQ2zvpZ9AFfzwsm6pc1AjsRT7cORBakBCQ42npX3wU8lLFysGygnNarjVUz7SIdaqaXmmT9o-uEYAjXTiS5lfgCEmeWL_04DI_0OVWD5D01r8w0vSZxt09H_jzZGHqT2U_E9aA1ulc6_PYvPapQjcEd3UFR7HVVRJoKI-HMpFJ2OToQVAJw-0Zj0Lzdz9pS3WFOOs8GWNT8rLk4iJQWkMrVWa-ec7HYrcOpCapccoI5MsO_jEdkUTuGgItC5L90cbHnFPffXkYDJTaxAZ8sindAepMFL61gxkUA-b5z6sL3ER-8aorKVUZQsXEDEMLh0CLh-wNsDrb3yOp8aRJxj-HW7bnKjXJTYgp1a6KdOJ_irX4dAHUcQNMrT3yI2TMsQc3qv7djk1PBUrz4sfNhGkFJW8bPr7dlh0DD9GHBHlz2B2DCeMCr0BtK_qpBx47uXtcChWt5PeykGllbgrMxXxXgctlv-3CK_JDZmt40EAkJ5dSKtSAmLxvEu6bFj_1aw6t_XrxEbzE-F--1dIlju82b39G7NTw-Ep0hr6OU1tYxBAHVNQmv7gAWe5H9Tdus9zOvwla-rbnejgX3gXjPFRmz9Lvu69Gfrg )
```

as you can see img is uploading from frontend and my api also works fine on postman its uploading the data but with guzzle its not working

```
function staff_profile_update(Request $request){
        $data = $request->all();

                $request_data = ['name'=>$data['name'],'userId'=>$data['id'],'phoneNumber'=>$data['phoneNumber'],
                'postalCode'=>$data['postalCode'],'city'=>$data['city'],'state'=>$data['state'],'country'=>$data['country'],
                'skills'=>$data['skills'],'image'=>$data['image'],'dob'=>$data['dob'],'staff_id'=>$data['staff_id'],'gender'=>$data['gender'],'first_name'=>$data['first_name'],'last_name'=>$data['last_name'],
                'token'=>$data['token']];

        $response_data = $this->apiService->multipartApiRequest("api/edit_staff_profile", $request_data,'post');


        if($response_data['status']== 1){

            return redirect('staff_profile')->with('data','profile updated successfully');
        }
        else{
            return redirect('staff_profile_edit')->with('data','Something went wrong');
        }

    }
```

multipart api services:

```
public function multipartApiRequest($url, $data = array(),$requestType='') {      

        $url = $this->base_url . $url;
        $client = new Client();
         $headers = [
             'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$data['token'],


         ];

     $image_path = $data['image']->getPathname();
    $image_mime = $data['image']->getmimeType();
    $image_org  = $data['image']->getClientOriginalName();
         $response = $client->request($requestType,$url,
         [
            'multipart' => [

                 [
                     'name' => 'userId',
                      'contents' => $data['userId'],

                  ],
                  [
                    'name' => 'staff_id',
                     'contents' => $data['staff_id'],

                 ],
                  [
                     'name' => 'phoneNumber',
                      'contents' => $data['phoneNumber'],
                  ],
                  [
                     'name' => 'postalCode',
                      'contents' => $data['postalCode'],
                  ],
                  [
                      'name' => 'city',
                       'contents' => $data['city'],
                   ],
                   [
                      'name' => 'state',
                       'contents' => $data['state'],
                   ],
                   [
                     'name' => 'country',
                      'contents' => $data['country'],
                  ],
                  [
                      'name' => 'skills',
                       'contents' => $data['skills'],
                   ],


                   [
                       'name' => 'gender',
                        'contents' => $data['gender'],
                    ],
                    [
                       'name' => 'dob',
                        'contents' => $data['dob'],
                    ],
                    [
                     'name' => 'first_name',
                      'contents' => $data['first_name'],
                  ],
                  [
                      'name' => 'last_name',
                       'contents' => $data['last_name'],
                   ],
        ],

                "headers"=>$headers
                ]);


        $contents = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);          
         return $contents;



    }
```

no everything seems fine but still same error Invalid resource type: array

postman api check data working:

[image]

Comment: what is this `Screenshot` ?

Comment: its image name...

Answer (score 0):

Your `multipart` array needs to look like:

```
$client->request('POST', '/post', [
    'multipart' => $data,
    'headers'  => $headers
    ]
]);
```

Where `$data` is an associative array in this format:

```
    [
        [
            'name'     => 'userId',
            'contents' => 2,
        ],
        ...
        [
            'name'     => 'img',
            'contents' => $request->file('img')->getPathName();
        ],
    ]
```

Comment: getting this error MultipartStream::addElement() must be of the type array, string given

Comment: make sure your header is outside multipart section.

Comment: Have you changed your $data array to make it look like the structure I proposed? (using name & contents keys)

Comment: your current structure of `$data` will not work - you have to change it

Comment: it needs to be in format `[ [ 'name' => 'userId', 'contents' => 2], ... ]`

Comment: so its basically what i tried to do ln second output with multiple name content

Comment: that's correct, leaving the `headers` array out of multipart and using `fopen` for `img`

Comment: and for the img part my api uploading the image in local directory and saving the path in db so there no need to open that image

Comment: the problem occur in this part 'contents' => fopen('localpath'.$data['img'],'r') as this file is not uploaded at this location its not finding

Comment: Your image is coming directly from an uploaded form?

Comment: can you remove the `[
                    'name' => 'image',
                    'filename' => $image_org,
                    'Mime-Type'=> $image_mime,
                    'contents' => fopen($image_path, 'r' ),
                   ],` and try again ?

Comment: still invalid resource type

Comment: and also every reload page get expired i'm sending csrf from form

Comment: can you add the function that is calling `multipartApiRequest()`

Comment: I'm running out of ideas.. you can try with a minimal array, no headers, no content, another endpoint, ...